# submenu staying on top of nav menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I cant get the submenu to lay under the main nav bar, i cant even get the fixed position for the submenu to margin at all, don't know what the heck i did wrong here. Full width Jquery animated hover menu.

`Demo` http://jsfiddle.net/MwChT/110/

anyone see what the issue might be, please give me some advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding `top: 50px;` to the CSS of  `#navigation_horiz ul li #dropdown_one`

where 50px is the height of the `<li>` items

Comment: Omar....easier said then done apparently as i'm new, and am trying to locate something to post this is answered and can not find it

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
#navigation_horiz .dropdown {
    //all other css
    //just add
    margin-top:10px;
}
```